# Comparing values in one column to get a calculated value if values are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-studio

I am trying to print a column with calculated values from two tables in SQL.  I need to compare both the `order_items` and `orders` tablea.  I have the below two tables:

Order_Items:
[image]

Orders:
[image]

Expected outcome. If there are different brands for an order_no in order_items table, it should show "multiple" in Brand column, if there are same brands the it should show the brand name:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can handle this via a single pass over the `Order_Items` table:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN MIN(brand) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) =
                    MAX(brand) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no)
               THEN brand ELSE 'multiple' END AS label
FROM Order_Items
ORDER BY order_no;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple aggregation. In this case a correlated subquery with the aggregation might be easier

```sql
SELECT
  o.*,
  oi.brand
FROM Orders o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT brand = CASE WHEN MIN(brand) = MAX(brand)
               THEN MIN(brand) ELSE 'multiple' END
    FROM Order_Items oi
    WHERE oi.order_no = o.order _no
) oi;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Drop table if exists order_items

create table order_items(
    order_no int,
    product varchar(20),
    product_codevarchar(20),
    brand varchar(20)
)

insert into order_items values(1,'product 3',13,'nike')
insert into order_items values(1,'product 1',11,'reebook')
insert into order_items values(1,'product 2',12,'adidas')
insert into order_items values(2,'product 4',14,'reebook')
insert into order_items values(2,'product 1',11,'reebook')
insert into order_items values(2,'product 10',20,'reebook')
insert into order_items values(3,'product 3',13,'nike')
insert into order_items values(3,'product 20',10,'nike')
insert into order_items values(4,'product 5',15,'adidas')
insert into order_items values(4,'product 2',12,'adidas')

Drop table if exists orders

create table orders (
    order_no int,
    customer varchar(20),
    revenue int
)


insert into orders values (3,'customer c',100)
insert into orders values (4,'customer a',200)
insert into orders values (2,'customer b',300)
insert into orders values (1,'customer a',400)

Drop table if exists #pk

select distinct order_no,brand into #pk 
from order_items

Drop table if exists #mb

select order_no,STRING_AGG(brand,',') as brands into #mb 
from #pk 
group by order_no

select a.order_no,a.customer,a.revenue,b.brands 
from orders a 
inner join #mb b 
on a.order_no=b.order_no
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).